# Implementation i18n in react js best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import i18n from "i18next";
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          "Welcome to React": "Welcome to React and react-i18next"
        }
      }
    },
    lng: "en", // if you're using a language detector, do not define the lng option
    fallbackLng: "en",

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss => https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation#unescape
    }
  });

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <h2>{t('Welcome to React')}</h2>;
}

// append app to dom
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

I just want best configure for localization.

I want to implement localization in my app. So i want to configure it as documentation. Is there any way i can manupulate my json file from admin panel.